# How to check if a specific page is already open in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-chrome, tabs

Basically, I've got a packaged web application which I'd like to be able to check as it loads if there are any other instances of the web application open, and, if so, to switch to the open instance rather than create another one.

Also, for the options page, I'd like it to be able to check if the application is open, and, if so, refresh the application page if the options page has been changed.

I've been reading the [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab) about the chrome.tabs JavaScript module, but I can't work out how to make the function look for a specific tab. I don't quite understand how to look for or set the tab ID for a specific tab. I think this is how to do what I want, but if I'm barking up the wrong tree please let me know.

If anyone here can explain it better for me I'd be most thankful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look inside the [Google Mail Checker](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#Mail) extension, which has this functionality:

```
function goToInbox() {
  chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(undefined, function(tabs) {
    for (var i = 0, tab; tab = tabs[i]; i++) {
      if (tab.url && isGmailUrl(tab.url)) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {selected: true});
        return;
      }
    }
    chrome.tabs.create({url: getGmailUrl()});
  });
}
```

In particular, you pass getAllInWindow the windowId (or undefined for the current window) and a function, which receives the array of Tab objects. You don't modify the properties of the tab directly; rather you pass its id to the update function in order to manipulate it.

Comment: That seems to select the tab perfectly! A question: how do I tell the browser to refresh the specified tab rather than switching to it as the Google Mail Checker extension does? And is there something similar to getAllInWindow that checks all windows?

Answer (score 4):

To make Josh Lee's answer work using version 2 manifest, you have to add permission to the tabs in the manifest.json file:

```
...
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]
...
```

I have no clue how this kind of construction adds 'security' to the web ...

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps the beginners!

With additional to #Josh Lee 's answer.

```
function openMyTab(mURL) {          

    if(!mURL){
       console.log("No url passed");
       return;
    }
  chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(undefined, function(tabs) {
    for (var i = 0;i<tabs.length; i++) {

// remove (tabs[i].url.indexOf(mURL)!=-1) and 
// use tabs[i].url===url if you want exact match below

      if (tabs[i].url && (tabs[i].url.indexOf(mURL)!=-1)) {

        console.log("URL Match found",tabs[i].url);

        chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url:url,selected: true});

        return;
      }
    }
     console.log("URL not found. Creating new tab");

    chrome.tabs.create({url: url});
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers while helpful - are quite old and outdated. "getAllInWindow" and "selected" are now deprecated. My code also refreshed the tab, like originally asked for.
I needed it to check for internal extension pages only, so here is what my code looks like:

```
function goToInternalPage(targetURL) {
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    for (let i = 0, tab; tab = tabs[i]; i++) {
        if (tab.url===("chrome-extension://"+ chrome.runtime.id + targetURL)) {
            chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id, {}, function(){});
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {active: true});
            return;
        }
    }
    chrome.tabs.create({url: targetURL});
});
```

}

A general version would look like this:

```
function goToURL(targetURL) {
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    for (let i = 0, tab; tab = tabs[i]; i++) {
        if (tab.url===targetURL) {
            chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id, {}, function(){});
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {active: true});
            return;
        }
    }
    chrome.tabs.create({url: targetURL});
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody planning to use above examples, "selected" option has been deprecated since Chrome 33, use "highlighted" option instead.